# How to serialize/deserialize a JS observable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

If I have an observable stream, using [RxJS](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS) or similar, like this ([marble](https://rxmarbles.com) diagram):

```
----1------2------3--4---|
```

How can I serialize that to a format like [NDJSON](http://ndjson.org) so I can save it in a database? Once it's saved, how can I reconstitute it as an observable?

For context, I want to capture a stream of user actions in the DOM (like mouse drags, etc.) and then replay them at a later time exactly the same as the user initially performed it.

Comment: Is timing important ? Do you want to preserve time ?

Answer (score 1):

If time is of the importance, you might want to store the time value along with the events themselves.

Little POC:

```
import { fromEvent, Observable, of, timer } from "rxjs";
import {
  map,
  tap,
  mergeMap,
  concatMap,
  takeUntil,
  mapTo
} from "rxjs/operators";

let latestCache: Array<{ time: number; event: MouseEvent }>;

fromEvent(document.getElementById("start-cache"), "click")
  .pipe(
    concatMap(() => {

      const source = fromEvent(window, "mousemove").pipe(
        tap((x: MouseEvent) => console.log(x.clientX, x.clientY)),
        takeUntil(timer(1000)),
        store( newCache => (latestCache = newCache))
      );

      function store(
        onCacheCreated: (
          cache: Array<{ time: number; event: MouseEvent }>
        ) => void
      ) {
        const cache = [];
        let lastTime = Date.now();
        return tap({
          next: (x: MouseEvent) => {
            cache.push({ time: Date.now() - lastTime, event: x });
            lastTime = Date.now();
          },
          complete: () => onCacheCreated(cache)
        });
      }

      return source;
    })
  )
  .subscribe();

fromEvent(document.getElementById("replay-cache"), "click")
  .pipe(
    concatMap(() => {
      if (!latestCache) {
        console.error("no cache yet");
      }
      return of(...latestCache).pipe(
        concatMap(x => timer(x.time).pipe(mapTo(x.event))),
        tap((x: MouseEvent) => console.log(x.clientX, x.clientY))
      );
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```

```
<h1>RxJS playground</h1>

<p>Open the console below to see results</p>

<button id="start-cache">Start Cache </button>
<button id="replay-cache">Replay Cache </button>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vxwurq?file=index.ts

From here on, you can store the array however you want, using the onCacheCreated function.